# How to add plugin version update option in plugin row action?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add version update option in wp plugin activation row.

Please get the attached link https://prnt.sc/rrgj0l

```
    $path = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
    add_action('after_plugin_row_{$path}' array( $this, 'call_back_plugin_row_action ' ), 10, 3);

    function call_back_plugin_row_action ( $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $status ) {
            echo '<tr class="active">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">Some Description for update</td>
           </tr>';
    }
```

I have used this code but nothing is showing ..check here https://prnt.sc/rrgbf5

Regards
Mainuddin

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want add custom text after plugin row.

**Example:**

```
$path = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
add_action( "after_plugin_row_{$path}", function ( $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $status ) {
    echo '<tr class="active"><td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan="2"><p style="background-color: #d54e21; padding: 10px; color: #f9f9f9; margin-top: 10px"><strong>Important Notice!</strong></td></tr>';
}, 10, 3 );
```